# Soccer-Head to Head

Tags: sql

I want to get sum(goals) both team from head to head Teaams
if i send query [team-Id] 1 & 2  will return 3-1
if i send query [team-Id] 2 & 3  should not return anything

```
 Tour-Id, Match Id, Team-Id, Goals
    1       1          1       1
    1       1          2       1
    1       1          1       1
    1       1          1       1

    1       2          1       1
    1       2          3       1
```

Comment: What? Show what you have tried and expected output please.

Answer (score 0):

Simple group by and sum will help to get your results

```
select tourid, matchid, teamid, sum(goals) from #yourtour
group by tourid, matchid, teamid
```

Good point raised by Jacobr365, What you have tried?

Comment: Thx Kannan,     i used        PARAMETERS teamA Long, teamB Long;
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Goal) FROM [Match Details] WHERE [tid] = teamA) AS Goals_Scored, (SELECT SUM(Goal) FROM [Match Details] WHERE [tid] = teamB) AS Goals_Scored2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [tid]  .
        FROM [Match Details]  )  AS tmp
GROUP BY tid;  But i need sum(goal) only teamA  played with teamB  not teamB played with other teams